# CSVHelper insert currency value into file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I have a decimal value that represents amount. I want to insert it into csv file like currency.

```
    await using var writer = new StreamWriter(csvPath);
    await using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>();

        await csv.WriteRecordsAsync(data);
    };
```

In the map class I did

```
Map(x => x.Amount).Name("amount")
                .TypeConverterOption.NumberStyles(NumberStyles.Currency);
```

As a result I have just decimal value '141000' not like currency [image]
Can I show in csv file decimal like currency?

Comment: Why would you even want this? Currency formats are highly sensitive to culture settings and it's very easy to get (silent!) conversion errors. Ideally only the receiving side formats the value like this from the numerical value, with the currency itself (if it can vary per row) in its own column. If you really do want a numeric value to get a particular culture-dependent format, you are much better off writing explicit code that does this (with `Map(...).Convert(x => String.Format(...)`), instead of relying on the CSV step, which should just be writing strings in this case.

Comment: After implementing in csv file I have smth like ########

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `TypeConverterOption.NumberStyles(NumberStyles.Currency)` is only for converting a string to a number. If you want to go the other way, you will need to use `TypeConverterOption.Format`.  I also found you can't use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. You'll either need to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or the specific culture you need the currency symbol for.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Amount = 141000 },
    };

    //using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Amount).Name("amount").TypeConverterOption.Format("C");
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanna. Thanks :)